# Are the Q affected by timeline changes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-q

The Q are an all-powerful race: they can shapeshift and create life almost instantly. But when the timeline is altered, what happens to the Q?

For example, in the *Enterprise* episode [*Shockwave*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shockwave_(episode)) the timeline is altered in 2152, causing earth to be in ruins in the 31st century. Since the Q are all powerful, it would seem weird if nearly a millennium of Q history could be erased, but there's no proof that that *didn't* happen.

So my question is, when the timeline is altered what happens to the Q?

Comment: The Q exist outside normal space-time (in a higher plane of existence or in an extra dimension if you like), so they are not affected by changes like that.

Comment: Also, https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_(species)

Comment: Take off their hats! Wait, no that's Popes in a Volkswagen...

Comment: “it seems weird that nearly a millennium of Q history can be erased” — was a millennium of Q history erased? How do we know they weren't sitting there in the Q continuum, watching humanity's history get rewritten and chuckling?

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out were they just chuckling or was 1000 years erased.

Comment: @BenjaminErickson: right ho. I'm not sure whether asking how they "fit in on the temporal plane" quite conveys that (mainly because I have no idea what that means), so I've edited your question to possibly be a bit clearer.

Comment: Relevant, but not a dupe: [Are the Q inherently four-dimensional?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53279/20774)

Comment: Another great question is whether The Traveler is affected by screwing with the timeline.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum--It's like Lt. Stamets in Star Trek Discovery--he only had tardigrade DNA, but it enabled to exist outside of and remain aware of the time-loop/time line. So the Q definitely wouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Q appear to be immune to changes in the timeline and can change the timeline at will and are present (*[singularly](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Q_Conflict)*) in [all timelines and universes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53279/20774).**

In *All Good Things*, Q alters the timeline of Earth by creating (or rather prompting Captain Picard to create) an inverse time rupture which explodes backwards in time to destroy the human race. Q and Picard, with the help of Q, are entirely immune to this incident despite traveling between multiple alternate timelines and managing the paradoxical nature of Picard's existence.

> **Q:** (continuing) *We wanted to see if you had the ability to expand your mind and your horizons... and for one brief moment, you did.*
>
> **PICARD:** *When I realized the paradox...*
>
> **Q:** *Exactly. For that one fraction of a second, you were open to options you'd never considered. That's the exploration that awaits
>   you... not mapping stars and studying nebulae... but charting the
>   unknowable possibilities of existence.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: All Good Things](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/277.txt)</sup></sub>

The Q can take things from the prime timeline and return them without creating addition timelines

> **JANEWAY:** (reacts) *You want to bring people here from Earth?*
>
> **Q1.** *I promise you it will not impact the timeline, and no one will remember ever being here when I send them back.*
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: Death Wish](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/voy034.txt)</sup></sub>

They have the ability to travel through time with total ease and no worry about the consequences of their actions.

> **TUVOK:** *Captain, based on our readings, it appears that we have been
>   transported back in time to the birth of the universe.*
>
> [Janeway looks sharply at Q2 who smiles as he watches the viewscreen...
>   acknowledging.]
>
> **Q2:** *Very old hiding place.*
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: Death Wish](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/voy034.txt)</sup></sub>

Q also seems to be entirely unaffected by the Narada incident and [interacts with the crew of the Kelvin-timeline Enterprise](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Q_Gambit) just as easily he interacts with the Prime Timeline Enterprise-D. Since this break in the timeline wasn't caused (as far as we know) by the Q, this would suggest that they're immune to non-Q-caused timeline breakages and alternate universe creation.

Comment: These were all cases where the Q did also cause the timeline changes. Is there any proof that they are immune to changes they did not cause?

Comment: @PhilippFlenker - Yes. If they weren't, Quinn would have just erased their memory of his existence to escape them

Comment: @Valorum: Quinn's a Q too though, right? How about changes not caused by a Q?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - What's the difference?

Comment: @Valorum: we don’t know, because we don’t know how time travel works in Star Trek. Sometimes (like in the 2009 movie) it seems to create a persistent alternate reality. Sometimes (Trials and Tribble-ations, All Good Things) it seems not to.